# R corrplot alternating row/column background colour

Tags: r, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

I have a corrplot with lots of variables, which makes it difficult to read which variables are correlated with which. Is it possible to make it more readable e.g. by alternating row/column background colours?

Example:

[image: corrplot]

Answer (score 0):

These will change the order of correlation. It might help see easier which values correlate with which.

```
      corrplot::corrplot(cordata,method="square",order="original")
      corrplot::corrplot(cordata,method="square",order="AOE")
      corrplot::corrplot(cordata,method="square",order="FPC")
      corrplot::corrplot(cordata,method="square",order="hclust")
```